# Custom setting insertion contributing to Lock Row exception which finally causes to ConcurrentLongRunning Transactions

Tags: apex, account, customsetting, locking

We recently faced ConcurrentLongRunning exceptions in our org. We resolved a few rest entry points which SF Support team suggested but few I am not sure if SF Support team analysis is correct.

We have a code to disable triggers for Account.

```
BypassSetting__c setting = TriggerHandlerRunner.createBypassSetting('Account');
Database.update(accUpdateList, false);
TriggerHandlerRunner.clearByPassSetting(setting);
```

---

```
public static BypassSetting__c createBypassSetting(String SobjectName){
    BypassSetting__c setting = new BypassSetting__c();
    setting.SetupOwnerId = UserInfo.getUserId();
    setting.Objects__c = SobjectName;
    insert setting;
    return setting;
}

public static void clearByPassSetting(BypassSetting__c setting){
    delete setting;
}
```

So firstly it will insert Custom Setting for the object we want to disable the triggers for, then fire Account update, so that no account triggers will run and then finally delete the `Custom Setting.`

SF Support team after analysis says that `And as per our internal discussion, the reason you are hitting the ConcurrentPerOrgLongTxn Error is not because of the trigger but due to the Row Lock contention while inserting the Custom Setting and Account Record.`

Is there some official documentation or unofficial documentation which supports this? How come inserting a custom setting and Account record causing a row lock issue. Have anyone faced this issue ?

Comment: Could you add more details when and where the error is occurring :  is it during normal execution or when running tests classes or during deployment, in sandbox or production org ?

Comment: @Shamina Its in normal execution process and its in production.

Comment: Not official and not entirely on topic, but I know that performing DML on Custom Settings has been a source of row lock errors when attempting to run tests in parallel. A bit closer to on topic: You're setting and immediately clearing the bypass setting. Is there any reason why you're not simply storing this as a static `Set<String>` in your TriggerHandlerRunner (which would side-step this issue) instead of in a custom setting?

Comment: @DerekF Yes I know there are multiple ways of avoiding triggers to run. There is no specific reason why we choose this one, its just one from many other ways. But wanted to understand how will this cause row lock issue. I read in this forum that parallel test classes would have this issue, but didnt get to know why.

Comment: @NagendraSingh Is it during test execution or during the trigger itself?

Comment: @MohithShrivastava Its not during test execution, it comes in normal execution.

Comment: My best guess is that it has something to do with how Salesforce stores custom settings in a special application cache (which is how we're able to access the data without needing a query).

Comment: Also, it would be great if you could look into the logs and see how much CPU time your transactions are taking and also time taken for DML

Comment: @MohithShrivastava We were not able to capture this from our end, but as per SF support team this operation takes in an average of 7-9  seconds. Not sure how though.